# Are these optimization problems equivalent?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

If $\alpha\,\, and\,\, p$ are non-negative scalars, are the two problems given below equivalent? I know that the values of objective functions will be different but I want to know will they result in same values of $\alpha\,\, and\,\, p$:

\begin{align}
Problem 1:
\min_{\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2}}\alpha_{1}p_{1}+\alpha_{2}p_{2},\\ 
\text{subject to}: \alpha_{1}log(1+p_{1} )\geq5,\\ \alpha_{2}log(1+p_{2})\geq5, \alpha_{1}\,\, and\,\, \alpha_{2}\leq1.\\
Problem 2:
\min_{\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2}}\alpha_{1}^{2}p_{1}+\alpha_{2}^{2}p_{2},\\ 
\text{subject to}: \alpha_{1}log(1+p_{1} )\geq5,\\ \alpha_{2}log(1+p_{2})\geq5,\alpha_{1}\,\, and\,\, \alpha_{2}\leq1 .\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. After the obvious reduction the problems are

*Problem 1:*
$$
\min 2ap\quad\text{subject to } a\ge\frac{5}{\ln(1+p)},\ p> 0
$$
*Problem 2:*
$$
\min 2a^2p\quad\text{subject to } a\ge\frac{5}{\ln(1+p)},\ p> 0
$$
The minimum w.r.t. $a$ is clearly for equality in both cases
$$
a=\frac{5}{\ln(1+p)}
$$
then we have

*Problem 1:*
$$
\min_{p>0} \frac{10p}{\ln(1+p)}.
$$
*Problem 2:*
$$
\min_{p>0} \frac{50p}{\ln^2(1+p)}.
$$
The first problem has no solution ("optimal" when $p=0$, $a=+\infty$), the second problem has a solution.

The green plot: $\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}$, the red plot: $\frac{x}{\ln^2(1+x)}$.
[image]

Comment: Actually I tried a bit brute forcing. varying the values of $\alpha$ from 0 to 1, taking a step of 0.0001, and calculating p that would satisfy the constraint. For both problems the minima occurred at the same values of p and $\alpha$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $\alpha \leq 1$

Comment: @ZainAli Oh, in this case $\ln(1+p)\ge 5$, so $p\ge 147$, and both objectives are increasing there. The minimum is at $a=1$ and $p=e^5-1$ for both problems.